# Does the array returned by .values from pandas DataFrame have different precision?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, precision

Computing std() of a pandas column I noticed that it differs from std(), computed from the numpy array, returned from the same column by .values method. Is there a difference in precision?

```
length = 5
fill = np.random.randn(length)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=range(length), columns = ["test"])
df2.test = fill
pandas = df2.iloc[:,0]
array = df2.iloc[:,0].values
print(f"pandas std: {pandas.std():0.6f}, numpy std: {array.std():0.6f}")
print(f"Difference: {(pandas.std()/array.std()-1)*100:0.2f}%")
```

pandas std: 0.764161, numpy std: 0.683486
Difference: 11.80%

With few numbers (here 5) the difference is quite palpable. Say with only 2 numbers the difference grows to 40%. The numbers in pandas and resulted array differ also in term of precision, but I thought that this is simply because pandas just displays 6 digits, while keeping the whole decimal length ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the precision of floating point values; rather, it is a result of [Bessel's correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction) being applied by `pandas` but not `numpy`.

Long story short, there is a `ddof` parameter for both functions that determines how the "raw" variance (square of the standard deviation) will be processed.

For `numpy`, it defaults to 0, meaning it is returned unchanged.

On the other hand, `pandas`, it defaults to 1, which means that it is equal to the variance calculated by `numpy` multiplied by `N / (N - 1)`, where `N` is the number of data points you have. If you call `std(ddof=0)` on the `pandas` object, it will return the same result as `numpy`.